# Cast using implicit operator overloading

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

Given two classes:

```
class BaseObject
{
}

class Some
{
    public static implicit operator BaseObject(Some d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some.implicit");
        return new BaseObject();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to cast from `object` (which is really `Some`) to `BaseObject` using implicit operator overloading. I've used explicit cast, but it didn't work because of `InvalidCastException`:

```
object obj = new Some();

var baseObject = (BaseObject)(obj); // InvalidCastException here
```

**Update**
For those who don't know about implicit casts. This works:

```
Some obj = new Some();

BaseObject baseObject = obj; // writes "Some.implicit"
```

The problem is that I receive `obj` as an `object`.

Comment: 1) `Some` does not subclass `BaseObject`, so how could this work even on first principles?  2) Why on earth would you want to do this?  We have type-safety for a reason.

Comment: @KirkWoll It's an huge project with a big history, it's hard to explain. Given two types which I can't change, I need to cast `object` to `BaseObject`.

Comment: but what does `Some` have to do with anything?  That's the part that seems very confusing.

Comment: @KirkWoll It's like how a cast from `int` to `short` doesn't throw an `InvalidCastException` either, despite `int` and `short` being unrelated types. In some cases, such implicit conversions make sense. In other cases, not so much. With the names `BaseObject` and `Some`, there's no way of telling whether it makes sense for the OP, so I'll trust the OP's judgement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the source and target type are known at compile time, the type of cast is determined at compile time too. In this case, `BaseObject` derives from `object`, so a cast from `object` to `BaseObject` is treated as a typical downcast, which fails if at runtime it is determined that the object is not a `BaseObject`.

To determine the type of cast at runtime, you need to use `dynamic`.

```
dynamic obj = new Some();
var baseObject = (BaseObject)obj; // works
```

or if `obj`'s declaration cannot be changed,

```
object obj = new Some();
var baseObject = (BaseObject)(dynamic)obj; // also works
```